# How do you find the caller function?

Tags: c#, language-features, callstack

**Closed as exact duplicate of ["How can I find the method that called the current method?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method)**

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/javascript-how-do-you-find-the-caller-function) possible with c#?

```
void main()
{
   Hello();
}

void Hello()
{
  // how do you find out the caller is function 'main'?
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method ?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
```

However, this is not robust, especially as optimisations (such as JIT inlining) can monkey with the perceived stack frames.

Comment: Hi, Marc. Would it be possible, because of JIT, that a method name could change during Runtime?

Comment: @Joe it is certainly possible to not get what you *expected*, which could be due to inlining, or due to compiler-generated methods for things like anonymous methods and iterator blocks. I wouldn't expect it to be suddenly renamed completely, unless you are using an obfuscator.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://bytes.com/forum/thread213910.html):

```
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace st = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(1);
System.Diagnostics.StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(0);
string msg = sf.GetMethod().DeclaringType.FullName + "." +
sf.GetMethod().Name;
MessageBox.Show( msg );
```

But there is also a remark that this could not work with multi-threading.

Comment: Many thanks for mentioning the remark. I was wondering why I got a `NullReferenceException` when I tried to get the method name from inside a new thread.