# C# Method Caller

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find the method that called the current method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method)

Hi,
how can i determine the caller of a method from within the method? Eg:

```
SomeNamespace.SomeClass.SomeMethod() {
   OtherClass();
}

OtherClass() {
   // Here I would like to able to know that the caller is SomeNamespace.SomeClass.SomeMethod
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280413/c-how-do-you-find-the-caller-function-closed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These articles should be of help:

1. http://iridescence.no/post/GettingtheCurrentStackTrace.aspx
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2005/03/20/399287.aspx

Basically the code looks like this:

```
StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1);
MethodBase method = frame.GetMethod();
message = String.Format("{0}.{1} : {2}",
method.DeclaringType.FullName, method.Name, message);
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

Comment: Do be careful.  I was caught by this bug once.  If you build your application for release, the method can get in-lined and your stack trace will look different.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe(VS.71).aspx) class

Snippet from the MSDN

```
// skip the current frame, load source information if available 
StackTrace st = new StackTrace(new StackFrame(1, true)) 
Console.WriteLine(" Stack trace built with next level frame: {0}",
  st.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [System.Diagnostics.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class:

```
  StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();           // get call stack
  StackFrame[] stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();  // get method calls (frames)

  // write call stack method names
  foreach (StackFrame stackFrame in stackFrames)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(stackFrame.GetMethod().Name);   // write method name
  }
```