# How can I get the name of NameSpace and Class dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#

I have two classes, Class A and Class B. These both classes are lying in two different namespaces.
I call a static method of Class B from Class A, then how can I get complete information of Class A and its namespace in called static method of Class B?

**I do not want to add any code in class A**
But can add anything into class B.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163435/c-sharp-method-caller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) method on your `A` object.

```
namespace nmspA {
    public class A{
        private void DoSomething(){
            B.Foo(this);
        }
    }
}

namespace nmspB {
    public class B {
        public static void Foo(A a){
            Debug.Write(a.GetType()); // Will write : "nmspA.A"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Through Reflection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.aspx

Answer (score 4):

```
obj.GetType().FullName;
```

or

```
typeof(AClass).FullName;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about you pass class A as a parameter to class B? Like:

```
public class A{
   public void CallB(){
      ClassB.MyMethod(this);
   }
}

public static class B {
   public static void MyMethod(A a){
       // get info about class a here.
   }
}
```

Of course, you can also look at the options you have with reflection if you do not want to pass the object as a parameter.