# Get current Step definition from of a Scenario in SpecFlow

Tags: c#, specflow

I'm contributing to a framework called [CodeSpec](https://github.com/surenr/CodeSpec) and it is built on top of [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/).

Using the `ScenarioContext` I could get the currently executing scenario's title. but I want to get the step definitions too.

Say the scenario is

```
Scenario: Google for Cats
Given I navigate to "http://google.com"
And I enter value "Cats" to the "searchBox" with the "id" of "lst-ib"
And I click on element "searchButton" with the "xpath" of "id('sblsbb')/button" and wait "4" seconds
Then The page contains text pattern "The domestic cat is"
```

I could get the title with the following code,

```
[AfterScenario("UIAutomationReport")]
public static void AfterScenario()
{
    var title = ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title;
   //title now is "Google for Cats"
    
}
```

I want to get the step definitions too like
`Given I navigate to "http://google.com"`, `And I enter value "Cats" to the "searchBox" with the "id" of "lst-ib"`, etc.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get this in the current version of specflow, but in the next release (v2) the information about the [step text and step type will be available from the ScenarioStepContext class](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/pull/425)

you can get a beta build of the new version from the [CI build nuget feed](https://ci.appveyor.com/nuget/specflow-ci).

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a release schedule yet. but you can use the beta if you get it from the nuget feed I linked to above.

Comment: `ScenarioContext.Current.StepContext.StepInfo.Text` works.The answer is outdated now

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code to get your step definition:

```
String title = ScenarioContext.Current.StepContext.StepInfo.Text; 

Console.WriteLine("Step Definition Title : " + title);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a caller name and attributes of caller

StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1);

MethodBase method = frame.GetMethod();

message = String.Format("{0}.{1} : {2}",
method.DeclaringType.FullName, method.Name, message);

Console.WriteLine(message);

See
[C# Method Caller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163435/c-sharp-method-caller)

In atributes is Specflow step description