# How can I prevent a function from being called outside another function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function (function1) that checks some global variables (can the user connect, is the service available, etc) before calling another (legacy) function (function2) that actually pops a window and connects the user to our service.  I want to prevent function2 from being called anywhere but from function1.  Is this possible?

As a cheap solution, I figured I could emit a variable from function1 and check for it in function2 before executing.  Is there another way? Is there a way to find out the calling element/method in a javascript function?

Comment: while declaring function2 is a valid solution, this is actually a simlified version of my problem.  there actually multiple function2s and it seems somewhat messy to declare them all inside function1.  that's why i marked the answer using arguments.callee.caller.  thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check this:

- [How do you find out the caller function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/javascript-how-do-you-find-the-caller-function)

and this:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller

Answer (score 4):

Read here: [Crockford's method](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html). Declare the function inside the first function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove function2, move its entire content into function 1 ?

Then you can just replace the old function 1 with something that signals the error.

Answer (score 0):

you can move function2 inside of function1 so that's it's "private" to function1.  check out the ["module pattern"](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var function1 = function() {
    var function2 = function() { alert('hi'); };

    function2();
};

function1(); // alerts "hi";

function2(); // error function2 is undefined
```