# Determine calling function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, callstack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you find out the caller function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript)

How can I find out in a javascript function which was the calling (the former in the call stack) function?

I would like to determine if the former called function is a __doPostback in the onbeforeunload event.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Each function has a `caller` property defined.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller:

```
function myFunc() {
    if (myFunc.caller == null) {
        return ("The function was called from the top!");
    } else
        return ("This function's caller was " + myFunc.caller);
    }
}
```

The `Function.caller` property is not part of the ECMA3 standard but it's implemented across all major browsers, including IE and Firefox.

If you're using an anonymous function, you can still access the `caller` property via the [`arguments.calee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) property:

```
function() {
    if (arguments.callee.caller == null) {
        return ("The function was called from the top!");
    } else
        return ("This function's caller was " + arguments.callee.caller);
    }
}
```

Note that this code is accessing the current function, and then referencing the same non-standard `caller` property on it. This is distinct from using the **deprecated** [`arguments.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/caller) property directly, which is **not implemented** in some modern browsers.

Comment: Note that `caller` is a non-standard property. Your mileage may vary across browsers.

Comment: Non standard property indeed but is there something similar in IE? It should only work in IE for my client, Firefox is not supported.

Comment: `caller` is not part of the ECMA3 standard but it *is* implemented in all major browsers: IE, Firefox, Safari. It should be safe to use in IE.

Comment: I've edited my response to cover the non-standard contention and added more info on getting the caller of an anonymous function.

Comment: FYI, just tested `caller`. As James says, very well-supported. Present and correct on FF3.5, IE7, Chrome2, Safari4 (all on Windows). Opera9 is the odd one out and is seriously broken: It has the property, but it refers to the _callee_, not the caller! (Scary.) Test page here: http://pastie.org/597543

Answer (score 0):

In chromeos on cr-48, arguments.callee.caller gives the whole function body as a string, for both named anonymous caller functions.

Comment: than how to get the name of the caller ?

Comment: @Umair `arguments.callee.caller.name`