# JavaScript - Get calling object

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Javascript how do you find the caller function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/javascript-how-do-you-find-the-caller-function)

Is there a way to get the value of `this` from the function which has called the current function?

Look at this:

```
function TraceMySelf(){
    console.log(this);
}
function A(){
    TraceMySelf();
    console.log(this);
}

var a = new A();
```

When this code is executed, the console displays first the `window` object and then the `a` object. How can I make the code display the `a` object twice, with only changing line 2? I know that I could apply the function inside `A` with `this`, but that isn't what I want.

Is this possible?

Comment: i think the only way is to pass it as an argument

Comment: No way without passing it as argument? @hvgotcodes: In your metioned question, he asks for the calling FUNCTION ;)

Comment: @FlashFan: Only functions can call other functions. Objects can't. You cannot get the object a function is a property of because there exist no inverse relationship. @hvgotcodes: Yes it is a duplicate, but it should be noted that the usage of `arguments.callee` and such, is deprecated.

Comment: And to be very exact: In your example, not `this` is calling `TraceMySelf`, but the constructor function `A`.

Comment: @Felix: You're right, but if there would be a thing like an "object stack", where i could access the "this" values of the functions in the stack, it would be possible. But there's nothing like this, right?

Comment: @FlashFan: I see what you mean. Afaik there is nothing like that. At least nothing what you can access from JavaScript itself.

Comment: @hvgotcodes There is a _DISTINCT_ difference in these questions

Comment: whouldn't the prototypejs bind achieve this goal? var fnc =TraceMySelf; fnc.bind(this)();

Comment: @Felix: Thanks for your help. Then I must solve it in an other way. @ Liviu: bind would do the same as apply or call. And that's not what I want.

Comment: @LiviuT you mean the ES5 native `.bind` ;) @FlashFan what do you want to achieve _in_ context. We can suggest an alternative design that could emulate this for you

Comment: @raynos, hmm it appears I cannot undo my close vote.  Sorry.  In any event, are you asking for the scope of the function that called the currently executing function?

Comment: @hvgotcodes @FlashFan more correctly he's asking for the `this` context rather then the `CallObject`. There is no way to get this through reflection you need to set up a different way of writing your code to achieve something similar.

Comment: @Raynos - If this many people are getting the meaning of the question wrong, then maybe it's a problem with the question and not the people answering. Furthermore, you could have edited the question to make it more clear in less time than it's taken you to correct everyone one-by-one.

Comment: @lwburk your right. I could have made the question more clear. I'll do that next time, Thanks.

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of that question. I have this same question but could care less about the linked "duplicate". Vote for reopen.

Comment: As a debugging hack, I've just created a debugging version of my function and did a search & replace of the code to use that version.  E.g:

    function myFunc(param) = { ... }
    function myFuncDB(caller, param) = {
        console.debug(caller);
        return myFunc(param);
     }

Then replace every occurrence of "myFunc(" with "myFuncDB(this,".

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the answer to your question: [StackOverflow 280389](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/javascript-how-do-you-find-the-caller-function/3789144#3789144)

However, I think the right answer is "don't do that". I think it runs counter to how JavaScript is designed.

It might also be worth looking at [jQuery Proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) for another way of linking function and object.

Comment: -1 Given the list of comments on the question, it has been mentioned that this is not the answer the user is looking for.

Comment: You're right, there is discussion above. Most of it hidden behind a <click for more> link. What isn't here is an answer. I don't think it's trolling to write one. Anyways. thanks for your feedback.