# How to find, which one is calling my function?

Tags: jquery

I have a function, that is called by interval function, as well on click on a link, my link will clear the interval, and call the same function again.

calling this types will do the different work, but i don't know how to find, whether my interval function is calling my function or onclick function calling my function..

How can i find the caller of my function?

This is my function

```
function slideshow (){
    $('#slide_viewer ul').css({marginLeft : -(slideWidth * currentSlide)+'px'});
    if(currentSlide == (totalSlides-1)){
        currentSlide = 0;
    }else{
        currentSlide++;
    }

}
var myInterval = setInterval(slideshow,3000);

$('a.control').click(function(){
    currentSlide = ($(this).attr('id') == "prev") ? (currentSlide = currentSlide-1) : (currentSlide = currentSlide+1);
    slideshow ();
})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you find out the caller function in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript)

Comment: Is this for debugging or of code functionality?

Comment: It's not helping me.. any sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
  arguments.callee.caller
```

to find who is calling your function.

A even simpler solution would be to flip a global variable when you are calling slideShow(). So when setInterval calls it your global variable will be false.

You can also use a closure and an argument to differentiate the cases as well

```
function slideshow(var autocall)
{
//your stuff depending of autocall false or true
}

var automaticall = function() 
{
   var autocall = true;
   slideshow(autocall);
}

var myinterval  = setInterval( automaticall , 3000 );


$('a.control').click(function(){
    currentSlide = ($(this).attr('id') == "prev") ? (currentSlide = currentSlide-1) : (currentSlide = currentSlide+1);
    slideshow (false);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment links to a good post, or you could pass something to your function from the interval call:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function()
{

    slideshow("interval");

},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the callee and caller functions. But these are depreciated in most browsers today T.T