# Is it possible to get the name of the function the code is executing in using JS?

Tags: javascript, function

For example:

```js
function foo() {
    console.log(functionPame);
}
```

would output `foo`

or

```js
function foo() {
    function bar() {
        console.log(functionPath)
    }
}
```

would output `foo/bar`

The format itself doesn't particularly matter, just that the information is available.

Comment: Out of interest, why would you need to know?

Comment: `(new Error()).stack` shows the trace of where the error was created. It seems odd to need this information outside the context of fixing an error.

Comment: @ADyson I'm trying to create a custom logger where the output would include the location where it was called, for example:
`[outerFunctionName/functionName] [INFO] whatever`

Comment: @grian in JavaScript, functions are objects and can be assigned to variables etc, so the "name" of the function essentially is a variable name, and these cannot be gotten (outside of using new Error().stack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Error().stack, see example:

i used this post: [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715571/how-to-get-result-of-console-trace-as-string-in-javascript-with-chrome-or-fire)

```js
function foo() {
    console.log(Error().stack);
}

function bla() {
    function bar() {
        console.log(Error().stack);
    }
    bar();
}

foo();
bla();
```