# How to know what function a function is inside?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, statechart

I am trying to create a statechart framework as a sparetime project.

CoffeeScript

```
Statechart.state "A", ->
  @state "B1", ->
    @state "C"
  @state "B2", ->
```

JavaScript

```
Statechart.state("A", function() {
  this.state("B1", function() {
    this.state("C");
  });
  this.state("B2", function() {
  });
});
```

I wonder if there is a way for the inner functions to be aware of the outer one, so that B1 and B2 know they are children of A and C knows it is a child of B1.

UPDATE: I used bind(). It worked great!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fat arrow `=>`. It uses an implementation of [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
Statechart.state "A", ->
   @state "B1", =>
       @state "C"
   @state "B2", =>
```

In this code, `@`/`this` will always refer to the `Statechart` object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold a reference to the value of 'this/@' inside the first function.

I would usually create a variable called 'self' as below:

```
Statechart.state "A", ->
   self = @
   @state "B1", ->
       self.state "C"
   @state "B2", ->
```

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. That is the API the users will use. The end result can't be altered. I wanna know how I could have the functions to be aware of the hierarchy behind the scenes. Someone told me to use bind(), I think that might work.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript/4047670#4047670) from @Francisco Soto's answer looks like it could be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one that is pretty full featured in straight javascript. [Stativus](http://stativ.us).  You can use that as a model to implement it in CoffeeScript.

Keep me up to date if you need help or have questions.