# How to find where the function is being called from on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an exported function in Node.js, and for some reason, it gets called again with the same data after some time (like 5 minutes later). For example, when I call it 3 times with 3 different variables, it will be called again after some time in the same order with the same variables and with the same delay between the calls. Now I'm trying to debug this and try to find the place where that function is being called from again. I don't have any loops, timeouts, nor I'm not saving the variables that are being passed to the function.

What tools or functions can be used to determine the caller of that function?

PS. Sorry, but no code example, because the answer should be general and can be used in various ways. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you find out the caller function in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript)

Comment: console.log(new Error().stack); on the fourth time the function runs would give you a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is with the fact that the call is located in the closure. It is difficult to say precisely without code. You can use [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) and [v8-profiler](https://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler) to debug your app.

Install node-inspector globally (require root privileges) via npm:

```
npm install -g node-inspector
```

Install v8-profiler to you app node_modules via npm:

```
npm install v8-profiler
```

Include v8-profiler nto your app and start profiling:

```js
var profiler = require('v8-profiler');
profiler.startProfiling('profile name');

// Critical code

// profiler.stopProfiling('profile name'); // If needed
```

Run you app in debug mode:

```
node --debug your/node/program.js
```

Start node-inspector:

```
node-inspector &
```

You can change default 8080 port with --web-port option:

```
node-inspector --web-port=8081 &
```

Open

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858
```

in your favorite WebKit based browser.

Go to the 'Profiles' tab and enable profiling. After thats actions every profiler.startProfiling call in your app will create new execution trace and you should see it in 'cpu profiles'.