# How do I get the name of the function that calls a method?

Tags: javascript

Consider the next example:

```
 function Test(){
    Log();
 }
 function Log(){
   console.log('Name of the called function');
 }
```

How do I get the name of the function, in this case Test(), Into my Log function without parameters of corse.

Consider that this works on this way:

```
function Hello(){
Log(); //should return Hello
}
function Test(){
Log(); //should return Test
}
function World(){
Log(); //should return World
}

function Log(){
return NAME_OF_FUNCTION;
}
```

Thanks

UPDATE:

I can use arguments.callee.name to get the name, but, this doesnt work on strict mode and If I delete de strict mode and I try to use it I get the name of clousure function and not the name of the parent method.. for example:

```
var Log = (function(){

function info(message){
console.log(arguments.callee) //This print function info(message){
}

return {
info:info
}
})();

function Test(){

Log.info("Some Message");

}
```

This is wrong, I need the name of Test function, not the info function.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this inside your function's body:

```
arguments.callee.caller.toString()
```

check this snippet:

```js
function Test(){
    Log();
}

function Log(){
    alert(arguments.callee.caller.toString());
}

Test();
```

**Update**

If `strict mode` is used the above will **not** work.

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript/235760#235760), to see that [Alex K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246342/alex-k) mentioned below in his comments. I didn't know it.

Comment: Wouldn't they just want `Test` in this case?

Comment: I don't agree with this answer. It appears that the user wants just `Test` and not the entire: `function Test(){ Log(); }`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek this is not possible as I am aware of.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorec I'm only want the name of the function, the answer below make exactly what I want. (arguments.callee.caller.name), but I use stric mode. So, I can use it.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
arguments.callee.caller.name
```

But careful: 'caller', 'callee', and <del>'arguments'</del> properties cannot be used in strict mode they are deprecated in ES5 and removed in strict mode.

Comment: Careful: `arguments` is not deprecated.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: nope

Comment: You are right arguments of course isn't deprecated, while callee and caller are.

Comment: `Function.arguments` is depreciated, `arguments` is not

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: the problem was that the answer claimed that `arguments` is deprecated while it isn't.

Comment: I need to use the strict mode, so, I can use this example. There is another way?.

Comment: As far as I know, this ain't possible in strict mode. There seems to be some sort of a hack, but its V8 only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777905/how-to-get-caller-from-strict-mode