# Calling Rest From Angular JS- TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, rest, factory

Hi I am trying to call Post web service from Angular JS. I am not getting the response instead getting below error.

```
TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context.
    at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:3:14)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/factory/bookFactory.js:24:17
    at processQueue (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16170:28)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16186:27
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17444:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17257:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17552:24)
    at done (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11697:47)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11903:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11836:9)
```

Here is my Factory Code which all another Web Service to get Hotel Information.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name myappApp.factory:bookFactory
 * @description
 * # bookFactory
 * Factory of the myappApp
 */
var app = angular.module('myappApp');
app.factory('bookFactory', function($http, viewFactory) {
    var booked = [];
    return {
        bookingConf: function(id, userName, userAddress) {
            viewFactory.getHotels(id).then(function(result) {
                var request = $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://hotelmgmt.mybluemix.net/book',
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                    data: '{"customer":{"name":"'+userName+'","address":{"address":"'+userAddress+'","location":"'+userAddress+'","zip":"'+userAddress+'"}},"hotel":{"id":"'+result.data.id+'","name":"'+result.data.name+'","address":{"address":"'+result.data.address.address+'","location":"'+result.data.address.location+'","zip":"'+result.data.address.zip+'"},"dayRate":"'+result.data.dayRate+'","nightRate":"'+result.data.nightRate+'"}}'
                });
                 // Store the data-dump of the FORM scope.
                request.success(
                    function( html ) {
                       return html;
                    }
                );
            });

        }
    };
});
```

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921189/caller-and-arguments-are-restricted-function-properties-and-cannot-be-access)

Comment: @developer033 no its not. Angular sometime gave this error on its digest cycle. I am using with simple ES5 not ECMA 6 but still producing the error