# Has Safari on iOS 13 changed the way that enable/disable strict mode?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, ios13, strict

I'm testing my web application on iOS 13 which in the date of this post is in beta phase yet. I got an exception related to a stack trace like this:

```
var g, C = void 0 !== (I = I || {}) ? I : {},
    B = {};
    C.arguments = [],
    C.thisProgram = "./this.program";
```

I just added the piece of stack code as is. This code is from the opencv-lite library. Safari in iOS 13 throws the error:

> 'arguments', 'caller', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context

I already searched about the error itself and the nearest discussion that I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921189/caller-and-arguments-are-restricted-function-properties-and-cannot-be-access).

The library is not on **"strict mode"** and *doesn't have the "use strict" on the top*. It's like Safari on iOS 13 is using strict mode as default for this script, but I want to believe that this is not the case, otherwise a lot of application would broke. I found a similar discussion about it [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/emscripten-discuss@googlegroups.com/msg08790.html).

**My question is**: maybe iOS 13 in fact has changed the way that enable/disable *strict mode*?

*Note: the same application not throws the error on iOS 12 and bellow. Only on iOS 13 beta.*

Comment: Please clarify - You intend to refer iOS and not iPadOS, correct? The distinction may be important since iPad OS replaces the iOS web browser with the "desktop-class web browser" which could change the behavior of the browser on an iPad.

Comment: You're correct @daddygames, it's iOS and not iPadOS. I was testing in iPhone 8.