# "arguments" and "caller" properties on function instances

Tags: javascript

The ECMAScript spec says constructor function instances have following properties:

- [`.length`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-setfunctionlength)
- [`.name`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-setfunctionname), and
- [`.prototype`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-function-instances-prototype)

But in the browser, I can see that a function instance has two additional properties:

- `.arguments`, and
- `.caller`

The only reference I could find to these properties in the spec was [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-addrestrictedfunctionproperties).

Why are these additional properties present?

Answer (score 0):

These non-standard properties are added to normal (ie. non-arrow, non-method, non-async, non-generator etc) function instances **in non-strict mode**, for legacy compatibility reasons.

It appears that the `.arguments` property was superseded by the implicit `arguments` [variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) (which is still [part](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-arguments-exotic-objects) of the specification).

Note that the object pointed to by the implicit `arguments` variable also used to contain a `.caller` property, but this was dropped in ES2017.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921189/caller-and-arguments-are-restricted-function-properties-and-cannot-be-access) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777905/how-to-get-caller-from-strict-mode) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript).

MDN for [`function.arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments) and [`function.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller).