# Jasmine spy which functions called a method

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I know I can see if a method of function was called and with which parameters. But is it possible to see which which functions called it? So in fact I would like to find out from where in my code a function is being called.

Comment: If you really need to find where in your code a function was called within a unit test, you have a problem and are about to have another one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to test this but you can mock the function you wanna call and use [`arguments.callee.caller`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript) inside the mocked function to get function that call your function.