# How can I get the name of function, declared as a variable, inside this function?

Tags: javascript, reflection

Example:

```
var someObject = function () {
        return this;
    },
    someMethod = function (param) {
        'use strict';
       return /*method name*/;
    };
```

Can I get name of the method (in strict mode)?

P.S. I wish use it for convenient logging for javascript code.

Comment: Is this really the best way of doing this? JavaScript can be so handy in thousand ways, why do you need reflection?

Comment: @DanLee
set_selected = function (isSelected) {
    log.trace(this + '.set_selected');
    var selected = this.selected;

I wish I could use something like an aspect programming methods for logging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you find out the caller function in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript)