# Get The Element That Calls a Function

Tags: jquery, function, parameter-passing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you find out the caller function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript)

I have the following code:

```
JS:
function myfunc(mynumber){
   console.log(mynumber);
}

HTML:
<div onclick="myfunc(5);"></div>
```

Is there a way, with jQuery, to be able to get the context of that element that was clicked inside the `myfunc` function, without passing `this` or `$(this)` as a parameter in the `onclick` attribute?

Comment: Yes, remove the inline `onclick` function and use a proper `$(element).on('click', function() {...})` instead, and all your problems are solved.

Comment: what are you passing in the function param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use jQuery to actually bind the event handler, that way `this` inside that function will refer to the element that triggered the event. You can use a HTML5 `data-*` attribute to store the number that you want to use for that particular element.

HTML

```
<div data-number="5">5</div>
<div data-number="26">26</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('div').on('click', function(e) {
        console.log($(this).data('number'));
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
  $( "div").bind("click", function( e ) {
    myfunc(mynumber)
  });
</script>
```

or with param

```
$('div').bind("click", {  Param1: 2 }, function(event){
    alert(event.data.Param1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you asked for. you can call a function with

```
myfunc.call(params);
```

now in myfunc, when you refer or use this, it refers to the context or DOM it was called from.