# Get iframe html or name from parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a page that loads few iframe's within itself. 
Each iframe can invoke parent function.
For example like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  parent.test();
}
```

I want to be able to find which iframe invoked test function.
I've tried to play with calleer.called properties but the best I could get is the function that calling test().
In my case it was $(document).ready function.
Is there a way to get the name of iframe (or it's html name) which calling the function?

Comment: Pass the information you need via parameters on the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a parameter to the test function it will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  parent.test('name of this iframe');
}
```

OR even better

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  parent.test(window.name);
}
```

Then you just need to use that value passed to the inside of the test function.

Comment: Yes, this will definitely work but that not exactly what I want. I want to get iframe name (or filename) without passing an argument.

Comment: @user2629489, maybe you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript/3789144#3789144