# Get element from which function is called in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to get HTML element from which function is called in JavaScript?

For example I have this in my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var myContainer = getElementFromWhichFunctionIsCalled(); // Possible?
        (myContainer.id == 'my-container'); // TRUE
    }
</script>

<div id="my-container">
    <script type="text/javascript">myFunction();</script>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Probably worth looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript But the simplest solution is to just have `myFunction(this)`, which would explicitly pass in the the DOM `<script>` object

Comment: @MarcB uhh ... `this` would be the global context (`window`), not the `<script>` DOM node.

Comment: or since you have the DIV ID'd, you can just call myFunction('my-container').  Within the function you can make use of the name you just passed in.

Comment: @durbnpoisn, it's too hardcode for me )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally came up with this solution:

Hope it helps someone.

```
/**
 * Creating a temporary element to fetch it's parent element.
 */
function getElementFromWhichFunctionIsCalled() {

    // Generating unique ID for temporary element.
    var trickElementId = 'trick-element-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);

    // Adding temporary element to the DOM.
    document.write('<div id="' + trickElementId + '"></div>');

    // Getting hold of added element.
    var trickElement = document.getElementById(trickElementId);

    // Getting parent element of our trick element.
    var foundElement = trickElement.parentNode;

    // Cleaning up (removing trick element from the DOM).
    foundElement.removeChild(trickElement);

    return foundElement;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you call it here, when `myFunction` is running, the document will only have been parsed up to the `script` element in `#my-container`. Because of that, you can use

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var currentScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
var myContainer = currentScript.parentNode;
```

to get the element.

Comment: Wow! Clever trick! ) Is it consistent with all rendering engines out there? Is it forward-compatible?

Comment: Your idea looks reasonable. However this trick is not working for me. It gets wrong script element.

Comment: Probably it gets complicated when you have other script elements generated on the fly by third-party services like Google Analytics etc.