# How do you find out the caller function which is in different file?

Tags: node.js

```
//foo.js

module.exports.foo = function foo() {
    //
}

// Bar.js

var f = require(./foo);

function bar() {
    f.foo(); // How to find out the caller function is `foo` ?
}
```

How do you find out the caller function which is **in different file** in JavaScript?

I've seen a similar answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280396/4234171).

But I got this logging :

```
debug: caller is function wrapper() {
    var fn = (this && this !== root && this instanceof wrapper) ? Ctor : func;
    return fn.apply(thisArg, arguments);
  }
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. What does "How do you find out the caller function" mean?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly then the answer is "You read the documentation for the module you are using".

Comment: From the question you linked, it seems like you're trying to find out, in `foo`, that it was `bar` that called `foo`. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: "Always read the plaque." - Or in this case, "Always read the docs".

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — That's what I thought when I read the question title, then I read the body and thought it was "When I'm writing function `bar`, how do I know that I need to call method `foo`?"

Comment: And if that *is* your question:  Don't. Just don't. Step back from thinking that's how to solve whatever problem you're trying to solve, and ask a question about the problem you're actually trying to solve instead.

Comment: +1 to TJ's last comment. A function shouldn't need to care about what called it. It should just do its job.

Comment: I am writing a global function to log the error from the module it is calling, so here I am trying to find out the caller function.

Comment: Sounds like you should just throw an exception.

Comment: @Quentin Actually, I throw an error and want something useful info likes the caller function name and line number. etc.

Comment: @Wongzigii: If you're already throwing an error, that information is in the error's `stack` (and the string its `toString` will produce).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am writing a global function to log the error from the module it is calling, so here I am trying to find out the caller function.

If you do really need to do that, I'd probably do it via `Error`'s `stack`:

```
function log() {
    var stack = new Error().stack;
    // ...log the stack
}
```

If you like, you can do some post-processing on the `stack` string, but I would tend to avoid it as the exact format can evolve from dot release to dot release of V8 (I can tell from your code you're using NodeJS).

Example *(requires a browser that supports `Error#stack`, like Chrome [which uses the same JavaScript engine as NodeJS] or Firefox)*:

```js
function log() {
  console.log(new Error().stack);
}

function foo() {
  log();
}

function bar() {
  foo();
}

bar();
```

Comment: @Wongzigii: No, sadly, a string, and it's not yet standard. There's been talk of standarizing access to error stack traces, but it's not there yet nor do I even see a current [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposals) for it.