# How to get the code line number where function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-ui

I searched a lot but could not get correct / updated answer (*arguments.caller.callee does not exist it seems*). I want to know the code line number where a particular function is called. I got [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30687518/5336818) solution where function caller name can be retrieved .

But I am calling my function in JQuery UI droppable.
For eg:

```
$("#id").droppable({

stop: function(e,u){

   main(); // I want this line number
}

});
```

Thats the reason I wanted to know the line number . Is there any way ?

Comment: i used `try{throw new error("line")}catch(e){console.log(e.stack.split(" at ")[1])}`

Comment: what does having the line number do?

Comment: @epascarello : for debugging

Comment: So use better console.log() statements that describe it.

Comment: @epascarello :  console.log() but where ? If I already knew where the the line of code is then only I can place console.log() over there . Function is being called at many places.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `console.error()`, it will show the call stack and the line numbers (at least in Chrome, when you click the small black arrow):

```
function foo(){
    bar();
}

function bar(){
    console.error("hello");
}

foo();
```

Will show:

[image]

Check this fiddle (`console.error` doesn't work properly in the snippet): https://jsfiddle.net/fs1qqe77/

Comment: I think this is good for chrome .  But can it be used in all browsers ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you only need it in the browser you're using for debugging, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I have try with `try` `catch` `throw`

Note: snippet works inside a `iframe` so line wont be correctly.

```js
var i = 2016;
i++;
var str = "Happy new year "+i;

try{
clog();throw new error("l"); 
}catch(e){
console.log("current line: "+e.stack.split(" at ")[1]);//current file and line
}


function clog(){
console.log(str);
}
```