# Angular 2: Detect from which component service is called

Tags: angular

I have **MyService** which is injected into **ComponetA** and **ComponetB**.

Is it possible to find out from which component is the **MyService.myMethod()** called?

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  public myMethod(): void {
    console.log('called from component: ' + component);
  }
}
```

Comment: you can detect by passing parameters, and get accordingly something like flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only solution would be to use a parameter which would be passed to the called function.

EDIT: Previous suggestion to refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript) would not work because it only works without strict mode.