# How to reference the calling Javascript module?

Tags: javascript

I am using what I understand to be the Javascript module pattern, and jQuery.

I have an app which has a public and an admin side.  Each has its own JS file, though some functionality is shared so I have extracted it to a common file.  Gulp combines the common + public files into a single file for use on the public side, and the common + admin files into a single file for use on the admin side.

The public JS file includes something like:

```js
var PublicFoo = (function () {

    var bar = function() {
        // ..
    };

    var init = function() {
        $button.on('click', Common.someCommonThing);
    };

    return {
        init: init
    };
})();
```

The HTML page where this code is needed fires it off like so:

```js
<script>
PublicFoo.init();
</script>
```

The admin JS file includes something very similar, also defining a `bar()` function, and calling the same `Common` module function.

```js
var AdminFoo = (function () {

    var bar = function() {
        // ..
    };

    var init = function() {
        $button.on('click', Common.someCommonThing);
    };

    return {
        init: init
    };
})();
```

The common JS file (shared and combined with both public and admin JS) includes something like:

```js
var Common = (function () {

    var someCommonThing = function() {
        // Do stuff.
        // When done, I want to call bar() in the calling module.
        // This does not work, throws 'Uncaught ReferenceError: bar is not defined'
        bar();
    };

    return {
        someCommonThing: someCommonThing,
        // ...
    };
})();
```

From the `Common` module, how can I reference a function in the calling module?

I know about `.caller`, but apparently [that is non-standard and should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280396/6089612).

I could maybe somehow pass in the name of the calling module as a parameter to `Common`, and reference it, but that seems ugly:

```js
// In PublicFoo
var init = function() {
    $button.on('click', function() {
        Common.someCommonThing(PublicFoo)
    });
};

// In Common
var someCommonThing = function(callingModule) {
    // ...
    callingModule.bar();
```

I could also of course extract the `bar()` call out and do it back in the calling module, but that doesn't seem so neat either:

```js
// In PublicFoo
var init = function() {
    $button.on('click', function() {
        Common.someCommonThing();
        bar();
    });
};

// ... and the same thing in AdminFoo
```

I feel like this must be JS modules 101, a basic requirement, and yet I can't seem to find anything about it, though I may be searching using the wrong terminology.  Or is the reason I can't find how to do this because it should not be done this way?

How can I reference the appropriate `bar()` from the `Common` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know about .caller, but apparently that is non-standard and should not be used.

Also it doesn't work in your case, as the caller is the event handler and neither `PublicFoo` nor `AdminFoo`.

> I could maybe somehow pass in the name of the calling module as a parameter to Common, and reference it

Yes, passing references to the thing that you want to be called is the way to go if you want `someCommonThing` to do different things after it has finished. Notice you really should only use such a callback when the thing is asynchronous, otherwise just returning and calling `bar` afterwards (like in your last snippet) is much easier.

> How can I reference the appropriate `bar()` from the `Common` module?

If both `bar`s might be loaded at once into the page, then there's no way around a parameter that references the callback.

However, that doesn't seem to be the case in your example - on one page, `AdminFoo` takes the role of `Foo` and on the other page `PublicFoo` takes the role of `Foo`.

So just reference only `Foo.bar` from `Common`! Let the respective pages fill it with the appropriate value, i.e.

```
var Foo = AdminFoo
```

on the admin page and

```
var Foo = PublicFoo
```

on the public page.

Answer (score 1):

Passing functions to other functions is very common and perfectly idiomatic JavaScript, so you could do it like this:

```
// In PublicFoo
var bar = function() {
    // ..
};

var init = function() {
    $button.on('click', function() {
        Common.someCommonThing(bar)
    });
};

// In Common
var someCommonThing = function(bar) {
    // ...
    bar();
};
```