# How to know what function called another in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to automatically know who called a specific function in JS?

Let's say I have this code:

```
function1() {
function2();
}

function2() {
console.log('the function who called me is ...' + <magic code here>);
}
```

When `function1` calls `function2`, is there any magic way for `function2` to know that `function1` called it, without passing any additional parameters?

Comment: Wouldn't that fatally undermine the whole point of decomposing functionality into individual functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/280389/4515720

Answer (score -1):

You can use `function2.caller`. Using `caller` property gives you the detail of the function that invoked it. And further use `name` property to get the name of the calling function.

```js
function function1(){
  function2();
}

function function2() {
  console.log('called by function' + function2.caller.name);
  console.log('the function who called me is ...');
}

function1();
```

Comment: Please don't give answers for questions which are dupes.