# Want to know from where the data is received : TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to know from where my data is coming from which class, from which method 
let's take an example like

```
EditValue(data)
{
  /* my operations */
}
```

Now there are multiple classes in my project which send the data to this EditValue(data) method. 
Is there any way in Typescript or in angular to know from which class that data is coming or from which class method that data is coming. 
like className.method somewhat like this

Comment: Why don't you have a second argument to `EditValue` for that?

Comment: I think you are talking about reflection http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-reflection-javascript-typescript

Comment: @Ali Shahbaz can you provide me with code for reflection if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know from try using
JSON.stringify(console.trace())

I am sure it will store your data in variable

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in the data that gets passed to the method itself. Assign it when making the call and get the details using data['yourTagName'] in EditValue

Comment: I don't want to that thing. I don't want my developers to write a class name or method name and send the data to my editValue method

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example, hope it will help you

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User = new User();
  constructor() {

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user.FirstName = "Ali Shahbaz";
    this.EditValue(this.user);
  }

  EditValue(data: any) {
    console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(data));
  }
}

export class User {
  public FirstName: string;
  constructor(){
    this.FirstName = "";
  }
}
```

and response is

[image]

Comment: it's not what I want, it's giving me the class name but I tried to retrieve it but it didn't work

Comment: This is the way you can access class name, `Object.getPrototypeOf(data).constructor.name` but for function you need call stack, but it's not standard and not recommended https://stackoverflow.com/a/280396/1203961

Comment: bro it's giving me: Object instead it should be CurdTableComponent. I am using it in service

Comment: will have a glance on that link you provided

Comment: I just went through the link that you provided and I got the error which is mention in the screenshot you provided in argument and caller

Comment: Yes, in my comments provided URL, they are clearly saying caller works in non strict environment. There's another way to check call stack but I don't think that will work for you. `new Error().stack`

Comment: wil try this ,if still it wnt work then try to thnk to apply through another way or process, thanks fr ur efforts bro