# How to determine where a function is invoked?

Tags: ember.js

Like in which hook of the component the function was called ?

I need to assert that a function in my mixin is invoked only in the didInsertElement() hook and not before, so that the function could handle the DOM.

Comment: You mean for testing or in production?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if `this.element` is in the dom like `document.contains(this.element)`.

Answer (score 0):

https://ember-twiddle.com/d3c73960184bc386683ade204268059c?openFiles=components.sample-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.sample-component.hbs

I have created a twiddle, this details you how to check if a function is called directly from didInsertElement. (This method uses error stack)

reference: [How do you find out the caller function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript)