# NestJs - Log specific function by determining the callers name

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

Currently I'm using the NestJs default logging and come up with something like this

```
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  private logger: Logger = new Logger(UsersController.name, true);

  @Get()
  public getAllUsers(): any[] {
    this.logger.debug('Getting all users', this.getAllUsers.name);
    return [];
  }
}
```

The log message will show up

> [Nest] 2926   - 01/05/2020, 7:39:19 PM   [getAllUsers] Getting all
>   users +2094ms

It would be cool to set the context parameter automatically to only need to write

```
this.logger.debugFunction('Getting all users');
```

because when logging controller, service and repository functions things could get a bit messy. So from the docs

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger#extend-built-in-logger

it's possible to extend the default logging behaviour. Taking the example from the docs I would come up with

```
export class MyLogger extends Logger {
  debugFunction(message: string) {
    super.debug(message, 'this.caller.name');
  }
}
```

This has been asked before here

[How do you find out the caller function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript)

but `this.debugFunction.caller` doesn't seem to be a good way because the docs clearly say

[image]

Is there a way I can determine the context (caller) automatically in a standard way for production code?

Comment: My question would be, do you really need to know the name of the function making the debug statement? If so just throw/catch an exception in the `debugFunction` and capture the stacktrace. From personal experience, using clearer debug messages negates the need for passing in (or determining) the calling function. You could also solve this using a "LoggerFactory" approach which I can show if you're interested...

Comment: Thanks. It would be cool to have a look at your factory code :) But this question is not critical. I was just asking for a more comfortable way :)

Comment: @Question3r I've got an old implementation of creating a transient logger that took in a context name as a parameter. You can see the code here: https://github.com/jmcdo29/zeldaPlay/tree/64dd32e17e2581d554d640d03675283a1f90b762/apps/api/src/app/logger. I've since created a new logging package that handles it for me which you can find being used in the most recent version of the repository. Might be of some use :)

Comment: The Worst Possible Way That I Can Think Of to Get The Function Name is below..

`const stack = new Error().stack; const functionName = stack.split('at ')[2].split(' ')[0];`
Please forgive me :(

Comment: It amazes me people are trying to write 200 lines of code, just because someone "thinks" `arguments.callee.caller` or `function.caller.name` is not good-looking, or nobody will need it...