# Bind every child function's context to parent function

Tags: javascript

Say I have a parent function that calls some child functions like this:

```js
function parentFn() {
   API.greet();
}
parentFn.name = 'john';

const API = {
   greet: function() {
       console.log(`Hi there ${parentFunc.name}`); // prints out 'Hi there undefined'
   }
};

parentFn()
```

Is there anyway to get a property of the parent function inside the API without adding a parameter to the inner function?

Comment: Why not add a parameter?

Comment: The code you've provided won't do what you've said it will do. It will throw an error because you have `parentFn` in one place but `parentFunc` in another. If you had `parentFn` throughout, you'd get `Hi there parentFn` because the `name` property of a function is read-only.

Comment: I've put the code in the question into a Stack Snippet. I didn't fix the apparent typo because it's not clear to me whether you meant to do something else entirely.

Comment: When you say _parent function_ do you mean the function that called your function?  Like, one level beneath you on the call stack?  If so, see [How do you find out the caller function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript)

Comment: Please tell us more about your actual use case so that we can find an idiomatic solution.

Answer (score -1):

There are two cases:

- Every "child" function can have only a single "parent". If so, just refer to that specific parent directly: `parentFn.name`.
- Every "child" function can be called by multiple others. In this case you *need* a parameter for the dynamic value.

Notice that if you don't want to declare an explicit parameter, you might able to use the implicit parameter `this` that every `function` and method has. It normally points to the `API` object in a `API.greet()` call, but you can change it like `API.greet.call(parentFn)` (although this is slightly weird).