# How can I get `this` of the caller?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a replica of python's f-strings, not for any real reason, only for fun.

What I want:

```js
f`Value of variable: {variable}`
```

Is there a way to do something like this? (pun intended)

```js
function f(str) {
    return str.replace(/\{(\w+)\}/g, (_, ident) => caller[ident]);
}
```

No big deal if it isn't possible, I'm just curious.

Comment: Is there a difference to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript

Comment: yes, there is, `arguments.callee.caller` is deprecated and as far as i know, does not return a `this` object.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of python f-strings already exists in javascript, and it is called template literals. To create a template literal, you would use backticks, and to interpolate values, you use `${}` (equivalent of `{}` in f string in python)

```
const value = 'World'
console.log(`Hello ${value}!`) // "Hello, World"
```

As to your other question of how to get the this in the context of where the function was called, you could use the `.bind` method to bind the function to a certain context. Otherwise, you can also just pass `this` to the function, which would also work.

More about `.bind`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: i know they exist, i *did* say that i was doing this for fun and not for pracitcal use.

Comment: Oh ok. Well I also just answered you other question about how to bind `this` to a certain context.

Comment: i want the user to call the function using backtick strings, `f\`foo: {bar}\``. i don't see how this would be possible using .bind(), i guess this just isn't possible...