# Static variables in an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, function, memoization

I'm trying to mimic static variables on a JavaScript function, with the following purpose:

```
$.fn.collapsible = function() {
  triggers = $(this).children('.collapse-trigger');
  jQuery.each(triggers, function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      collapse = $(this).parent().find('.collapse');
    })
  })
}
```

How do I save the "collapse" object so it doesn't have to be "found" on each call? I know that with named functions I could do something like "someFunction.myvar = collapse", but how about anonymous functions like this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can save your variable in the function, using either `functioName.myVar = value` or `arguments.callee.myVar = value` if you don't have the current function name.

`arguments.callee` is the current function you are in.

Comment: What about an arrow function?

Answer (score 10):

For anonymous function you could use a function that returns a function.

For instance:

```
var myAnonymousFunction = (function(){
    var myFirstStatic = $("#anElement");
    var anotherStatic = true;
    return function(param1,param2) {
        // myFirstStatic is in scope
        // anotherStatic also
    }
})();
```

Should work like a charm and you're assured initialisation code for statics is only executed once.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that a better answer to this question is found [elsewhere on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript).

In short, you can actually give anonymous functions names without polluting the namespace, yet still allow self-referencing.

```
mything.prototype.mymethod = function myKindOfFakeName() {
    myKindOfFakeName.called = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're assigning the function to a variable like that, you should be able to access it as `$.fn.collapsible`, and thus assign variables as `$.fn.collapsible.myvar`.

Comment: That wouldn't work because that's not the function I'm trying to attach a variable to. Thanks.