# jQuery events. Send information to an event where he was called

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

What would be the best way to send a message to the click event to find out from where it was called?.

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(ev){

   if (called from funcion One or Two){
     //my code
   }

});

funOne = function(){
  $("#mybutton").click();   
};

funTwo = function(){
  $("#mybutton").click();   
};
```

**EDIT:**

on a ["trigger"](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger) I have a small solution, but depends on all implement the parameter "data"

**EDIT (II):**

My solution based on a '@Roatin Marth' Answer.

```
jQuery.fn.trigger = function(event, data) {

    var type = event.type || event,
        expando = "jQuery" + (+new Date);

    event = typeof event === "object" ?
    // jQuery.Event object
        event[expando] ? event :
    // Object literal
        jQuery.extend(jQuery.Event(type), event) :
    // Just the event type (string)
        jQuery.Event(type);

    if (!event.caller) {
        var xcaller = "";
        try {
            xcaller = arguments.callee.caller;
        } catch (ex) { };
        event.caller = xcaller;
    }

    return this.each(function() {
        jQuery.event.trigger(event, data, this);
    });
};


jQuery.fn.click = function(fn) {

    var returned = null;

    if (fn) {
        returned = this.bind('click', fn)
    } else {
        var event = jQuery.Event('click'), xcaller = "";
        try {
            xcaller = arguments.callee.caller;
        } catch (ex) { };
        event.caller = xcaller;
        returned = this.trigger(event);
    }

    return returned;
};
```

Comment: is #myButton dynamically generated to the page, so there will be multiple instances of it or something?

Comment: "$("#mybutton").click();" is called from multiple scripts, as the project is great, I need to know from that place is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass data when triggering an artificial event, the catch is you can't use the shortcut functions like `click()`, but instead use **[`trigger`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger)** directly:

```
$("#mybutton").tigger('click', ['One', 'Two']);
```

Click handler:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(ev, customArg1, customArg2) {
  customArg1; // "One"
  customArg2; // "Two"
})
```

Seeing as how `.click()` is just a shortcut to `.trigger('click')` anyway, you don't lose anything by doing it this way, just more keystokes ;)

---

*Edit addressing comments*:

> the system is already written and is
>   large enough to make a change in all
>   scripts

In this case you might need to hack jQuery to capture `arguments.callee.caller` and pass it along to your handler:

```
jQuery.fn.click = function(fn) {
  return fn ? this.bind(name, fn) : this.trigger(name, [arguments.callee.caller]);
};
```

With that patch, code that calls `.click()` directly will now pass their calling function scope info on to your click handler, which now can do this:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(ev, caller) {
   if (caller === funOne || caller === funTwo){
     //my code
   }
});
```

If what [this says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript/103961#103961) is true, then `arguments.callee.caller` is not going to be reliable in the future, but then, a hack is called a hack for a reason ;)

Comment: yes, I saw this option, but the system is already written and is large enough to make a change in all scripts

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I believe, when you do a click based on your snippets it will always trigger:</strike>

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(ev){

   if (called from funcion One or Two){
     //my code
   }

});
```

and not any of that functions... ( anyone? correct me if I'm wrong... )

EDITED..

ahh.. I see now... you wanted it dynamic clicked... (thinking...)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for arguments.callee. Now form javascript 1.4 it was deprecated.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript) for more details.

Comment: jQuery to be the manager for the event, the caller is a jQuery method

Comment: @Teja: this doesn't work. `click()` doesn't actually call the handler directly. It goes through an entire jQuery internal code path. `arguments.callee.caller` is meaningless as is by the time the handler is reached.