# Removing an anonymous event listener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Removing an anonymous event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106605/removing-an-anonymous-event-listener)

I have the following cross browser function to add an event listener:

```
_SU3.addEventListener = function(elem, eventName, fn) {
if(elem.addEventListener ) {
    elem.addEventListener(eventName, fn, false);
  } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
      elem.attachEvent('on'+eventName, fn);
  } 
};
```

I'm adding the listener like this:

```
_SU3.addEventListener(_show, "click", function(event) { 
                             _SU3.getChildren(_show, uri, element); 
                    });
```

Which is all fine. However I want to remove the listener after it has been called once. I.e. something like:

```
_SU3.getChildren = function(_show, url, element) {

... blah... 

_SU3.removeEventListener(_show, 'click', ANON_FUNCTION);

};
```

But of course the listener function is anonymous so there's no function name to reference.

How can I remove the listener?

Comment: You have to keep a reference somewhere. Either explicitly by passing a reference to your function, or implicitly inside your function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the function:

```
var foo = function(event) { _SU3.getChildren(_show, uri, element); };

_SU3.addEventListener(_show, "click",  foo);
```

...

```
_SU3.getChildren = function(_show, url, element) {

... blah... 

_SU3.removeEventListener(_show, 'click', foo);

};
```

Make sure that the variable `foo` is in the scope of where you remove the event listener.

Comment: Thanks. But this listener is being added to many elements on the page, so I can't have a global variable as this will get overwritten if the listener is called on other elements.

Comment: @Richard: I didn't say it had to be global, I said it had to be in the scope.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. If you want to remove it, you have to store a reference to it. How else would you be able to distinguish it from the others?

Comment: Well I'm perfectly happy to clear all click listeners attached to an element if that is possible?

Comment: No, there's no such function.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of *removing* the event listener, arrange for it to keep track of whether it's been called:

```
addOneShotListener = function(elem, eventName, fn) {
  var triggered = false, handler = function(ev) {
    if (triggered) return;
    fn(ev);
    triggered = true;
  };

  if(elem.addEventListener ) {
    elem.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
  } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
    elem.attachEvent('on'+eventName, handler);
  } 
};
```

That variation on your original function just wraps the original handler (the "fn" passed in) with a function that only calls the handler the first time it is invoked.  After that, it sets a flag and won't ever call the original handler function again.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion, thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you only have one click event assigned at any one time to an element, why not set the onclick property? You can remove it anytime with element.onclick='';

Comment: Because the page is dynamically built, and I've found that doing node.setAttribute('onclick', 'function') does not work in some browsers

Comment: He said property, not attribute.

Comment: object.onclick = function(e) {//etc};