# How to remove an anonymous event listener?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

So I've run across a problem that has been addressed in other languages but not in Corona/Lua. How does one remove an event listener with an anonymous function?

It would seem that one is supposed to 'store a reference to the function' but I'm not sure of the syntax for that in Lua. I've spent some time looking it up, and the closest match I could find was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616525/javascript-removing-an-anonymous-event-listener), which isn't very helpful to me, being in Javascript and all.

Comment: Do you intend to have the listener remove itself? If not, how do you know when you've got the right listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua has no such thing as "remove event listener". This is handled by libraries/frameworks that use event listeners, in your case Corona. I have no experience with Corona, but have you looked at [removeEventListener() documentation](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/objectremoveeventlistener)?

It seems you just need to save the reference to your listener to be able to remove it later. That is, instead of doing this:

```
Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", function() ... end )
-- cannot remove the listener, because you have no reference to it
```

Do this:

```
-- store a reference to your listener, so that you can remove it
-- equivalent to: local handler; handler = function() ... end
local function handler() Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", handler) end
Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", handler )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I gave you a plus for putting it in English. :)

Answer (score 0):

Storing the reference to a function is exactly the same as storing a reference to a variable. In order to manipulate an object later you need to give it a name, right? Well, the same goes for functions.

Incidentally, this is only an issue when using a function as the listener. However there's another style of doing event listeners, where you use a table as the listener and then have a function in the table named after the event:
http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/application-programming-guide-event-handling#Listeners_and_Event_Delivery

I generally prefer using table listeners.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, above answer is nonsense! do it like this:

local function xyz() blabla
end

--or

local xyz = function() blabla
end

--add listener

Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame', xyz)

--remove it again

Runtime:removeEventListener('enterFrame', xyz)