# How to store a reference to an anonymous event listener?

Tags: javascript, events

I'm not sure how I can store a reference to an anonymous event listener, so I can remove it at a later point.

[Removing an anonymous event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106605/removing-an-anonymous-event-listener)

This: [Removing an anonymous event listener2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616525/javascript-removing-an-anonymous-event-listener) haven't helped me.

```
   class Dragable
    {
        constructor(gameObject)
        {
            //Store reference to the event handler.
            document.addEventListener('mousedown', (mouseEvent) => this.click(mouseEvent));

        }

        click(mouseEvent)
        {
            console.log("Clicking..");
            //Remove eventhandler by reference.
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason because you want to do that, it's to keep `this` pointing to your object instance, instead of document, is that correct?

In this case, you can actually do several thing.

1) Just store the reference of the function in your object:

```
   class Dragable {
     constructor(gameObject) {
       this._listener = (mouseEvent) => this.click(mouseEvent);
       document.addEventListener('mousedown', this._listener)
     }

     click(mouseEvent) {
       console.log("Clicking..");
       //Remove eventhandler by reference.
      }

      destroy() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this._listener)
      }
  }
```

Also, if you're in a module, you can encapsulate `_listener` as private symbol in order to do not make it accessible easily from the outside.

2) Use a static "click" handler, then you bound to the instance:

```
  class Dragable {
    constructor(gameObject) {
      this.click = Dragable.click.bind(this);
      document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.click)
    }

    static click(mouseEvent) {
      console.log("Clicking..");
      //Remove eventhandler by reference.
     }

     destroy() {
       document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.click)
     }
  }
```

(You could also avoid static and just have `this.click = this.click.bind(this)` but I don't like overriding like that, but that's a personal taste)

3) You can use an event handler object instead of a function:

```
  class Dragable {
    constructor(gameObject) {
      document.addEventListener('mousedown', this);
    }


    handleEvent(mouseEvent) {
      console.log("Clicking..");
      //Remove eventhandler by reference.
     }

     destroy() {
       document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this)
     }
  }
```

Using `handleEvent`, inside `this.click` the `this` will point to your object instance and not document: notice that if you have multiple events to subscribe, you have to use a `switch(event.type)` to delegate to the right method. More info about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener/handleEvent

Answer (score 2):

Store the reference before you pass it to the function. Then use it everywhere you need it.

```
this.listener = (mouseEvent) => this.click(mouseEvent)
document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.listener);
```

Comment: @JaromandaX — You *can*, but it's overly complicated and hard for maintainers to read. Don't mix assignment and argument passing in the same expression.