# How to remove an event listener in javascript?

Tags: javascript, touch

I am wondering how can I remove an event listener after adding one, the way you use on and off in jquery?

```
document.removeEventListener('touchstart');
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
     closePopupOnClick(e, popup);
});
```

but this does not actually remove the event listener.  If I put the addEventListener code in a function and pass that function into the the removeEventListener it will not work bc you cannot pass params into the function.  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: remove event listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener) also [Javascript:Removing an anonymous event listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106605/removing-an-anonymous-event-listener)

Comment: no that question doesn't address the issue of params.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Put the listener as a variable and attach via [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)

```
var myListener = function (e) {
    closePopupOnClick(e, popup);
};
document.addEventListener('touchstart', myListener, true);
```

then pass it again when removing with [`.removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeEventListener)

```
document.removeEventListener('touchstart', myListener);
```

---

If you're **not** in strict mode you can make a listener remove itself with `arguments.callee`

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
    closePopupOnClick(e, popup);
    document.removeEventListener('touchstart', arguments.callee);
}, true);
```

If you are in strict mode, you have to use a **named function expression** if you want a function to remove itself

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function myListener(e) {
    closePopupOnClick(e, popup);
    document.removeEventListener('touchstart', myListener);
}, true);
```

---

If you want to use variables in the listener that may be changed by something (e.g. a loop), then you can write a generator function, for instance

```
function listenerGenerator(popup) {
    return function (e) {
        closePopupOnClick(e, popup);
    };
}
```

Now you can create the listener with `listenerGenerator(popup)` and it will scope the `popup` variable. Note that if `popup` is an *Object*, it will be *ByRef* and therefore may still be subject to changes.

Comment: how does one pass, the e and popup params to the myListener function in the addEventListener? thats what I'm stuck on the most. is the params.

Comment: Where are `e` and `popup` coming from? `e` is the _Event_ ? then you need to set _useCapture_ `true`

Comment: The addEventListener function is inside of a function that gets the popup param passed into it. So it comes from the outer function. e is the event. how do I set userCapture?

Comment: @Tanya _useCapture_ is the third parameter of `addEventListener`; the parameters being _type_, _listener_ and (optional) _useCapture_ (defaults to `false`). Please read the link in my answer for more details.

Comment: Use grave accents `\`` to make code blocks in comments. Simply remove `popup` from the parameter list of `closePopupTouch`; i.e.  `closePopupTouch = function (e) { closePopupOnClick(e, popup); };`. This means `popup` inside the function will be taken from the scope in which the function is defined. Where I was talking about `listenerGenerator`, that was to create a new scope for `popup` to protect the copy inside the function from any changes outside.

Comment: Consider this; `var i = 2, fn = function () {return i === 2;};`, now `fn()` gives `true`, but `i = 3; fn();` gives false. However, if you did `var i = 2, fn = (function (i) {return function () {return i === 2;};}(i));`, then `fn()` is `true` and  `i = 3; fn();` is true, too, because the `i` in `fn` got protected in it's own scope.

Comment: removeEventListener doesn't seem to work without the same value for useCapture as addEventListener:   document.removeEventListener('touchstart', arguments.callee, true);