# Why can't I clear an event listener in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

With timeouts, I can do something like

```
let x = setTimeout(func, 0);
clearTimeout(x);
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
let x = document.addEventListener("click", func);
clearEventListener(x);
```

I can't seem to ever find a straightforward way of doing this and it comes up quite often.

Comment: `document.removeEventListener('click', func);` ??

Comment: You might want to Google for the "removeEventListener" method, built in to remove event listeners.

Comment: No, because if I add the same function twice, and call removeEventListener, then it removes both of them. That doesn't happen when I use clearTimeout

Comment: can you add the same function twice? I tried 2 `.addEventListener("click", f)`, and it's called only once ..

Comment: *"No, because if I add the same function twice,"* Why are you adding the same function twice? That makes no sense. Also @Slai is right, you cannot add the same handler twice: *"If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on the same EventTarget with the same parameters, the duplicate instances are discarded. They do not cause the EventListener to be called twice, and they do not need to be removed manually with the removeEventListener() method."* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Other_notes

Comment: Unless you provide more information and a better example of your situation, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/15100576/218196

Answer (score 2):

Below is example code that adds an event listener to an element and then removes it the first time the event is handled. You can confirm that the event listener is removed by clicking the button a second time and observing that the handler function isn't executed.

```js
var eventHandler = function(e) {
  console.log('Handled the event once - now I\'m going to remove the eventListner via removeEventListener.');
  //remove the event handler
  e.target.removeEventListener('click', eventHandler);
}

//add an event handler
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', eventHandler);
```

```html
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Example">
```

Here is the mdn documentation for those methods:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener