# How to address addDomListener() deprecation in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I call `addDomListener` or `addDomListenerOnce`:

```js
const domNode = document.getElementById('...');
google.maps.event.addDomListener(domNode, "mouseover", () => { ... })
```

I keep getting the following console warning:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener() is deprecated, use the standard addEventListener() method instead: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
The feature will continue to work and there is no plan to decommission it.
```

How do I migrate to `addEventListener` without breaking anything?

Comment: I am not using addDomListener or addDomListenerOnce, but still getting the same Warning many times. How is that even possible? Any ideas on how to deal with this issue?

Comment: I suppose any of the third party libs (infobubble, marker clusterer etc) might still be using them? That’d be the first thing I would check.

Comment: thanks, yes markerclustererplus (now deprecated) is using addDomListener

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Both `addDomListener` and `addDomListenerOnce` were [deprecated on Apr 7, 2022](https://developers.google.com/maps/deprecations?hl=en#googlemapseventadddomlistener_and_googlemapseventadddomlisteneronce_deprecated_on_april_7_2022) but they

> …will continue to work and there is no plan to decommission them.

If you want to get rid of the warnings, proceed as follows:

#### `addDomListener` alternative

As advised in the official docs, you should migrate to the [native DOM's `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

So instead of:

```js
const domNode = document.querySelector('...');

google.maps.event.addDomListener(domNode, 'mouseover', (evt => {
  // handle mouseover
}));
```

you'd do:

```js
domNode.addEventListener('mouseover', (evt => {
 // handle mouseover
}));
```

In both cases, the listener's `evt` argument keeps implementing the [DOM `Event` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) -- depending on the [event type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

#### `addDomListenerOnce` alternative

Similar to above but with the addition of the [`once` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters). So instead of:

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce(domNode, 'click', (evt) => {
  // handle clicks
});
```

you'd do:

```js
domNode.addEventListener('click',
  (evt) => {
    // handle clicks only once
  },
  { once: true }
);
```

#### The return types changed

Note that google's `addDomListener[Once]` both [return a **`MapsEventListener`**](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/google.maps/index.d.ts#L8095).

That's not the case for the DOM's `addEventListener` which [returns **`void`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#return_value).

So if you were previously storing your listeners — usually to [remove/detach them](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/event#MapsEventListener.remove) later on — you'll need to keep track of them in some other way… Check out [How to remove an event listener in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100576/how-to-remove-an-event-listener-in-javascript) or let the browser's garbage collector detach the listeners for you.

---

Tip: `addEventListener` also supports the `passive` option which can [greatly improve performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners).