# google.maps.event.addDomListener() is deprecated, use the standard addEventListener() method instead : Google Place autocomplete Error

Tags: javascript, django, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to add  Google place auto suggest, I copied the code from the developer's website to try it out but got the error :
**google.maps.event.addDomListener() is deprecated, use the standard addEventListener() method instead.**
Also I am not getting any place suggestions.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

`google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeAutocomplete);`

i have also added script
`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=api_key&libraries=places"></script>`

I have implemented the same thing in one html it worked successfully, but when I used it on click button which opens a popup (**form which has place-input**), it gave me this error.

**Note :**  I have also tried *addEventListener* but that's giving me an error :  `google.maps.event.addEventListener is not a function`

Do you have any idea why I am getting this error, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Good to know that if you're using libraries like `@angular/google-maps` you wont be able to fix this issue. As of today, the `14.0.4` still have this error.

Comment: For more details see comment below, however be aware that when you load the Google Maps API you can just pass your initializeAutocomplete function via the URL like so: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js Then add on: ?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&callback=initAutocomplete

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to address addDomListener() deprecation in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71990197/how-to-address-adddomlistener-deprecation-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 26):

As addDomListener() is deprecated, use the standard addEventListener() method instead, you can do so as follows:

```
window.addEventListener('load', initializeAutocomplete)
```

Replace in a similar fashion at all the required places.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(<OBJECT>,<EVENT>,<FUNCTION>);
```

to

```
<OBJECT>.addEventListener(<EVENT>,<FUNCTION>);
```

Comment: Probably doesn't need to be said, but just in case, for jQuery you can use `$( window ).on( 'load', myFunction );`

Comment: Where should I add // google.maps.places.Autocomplete // ?

Comment: [google.maps.event.addEventListener] is not a function error triggers - so the "you can just replace" suggestion is not entirely accurate...

Answer (score 6):

This is not as easy as just "Replace addDomListener" with copy/paste. lol. that would be nice, right?

It should also be noted that when you LOAD the Google Maps API you can just pass your initializeAutocomplete function via the URL like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete'></script>
```

So, its as easy as tacking a callback GET var onto this url: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&callback=initAutocomplete`

in your example just add `&callback=initAutocomplete` = done.

#### full stop

**Lets examine other cases** - consider the following usage. This (from the old google maps example archive) is not going to work anymore:
[image]

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener( radioButton, 'click', function() { 
    autocomplete.setTypes( ['establishment'] ); 
  // this causes google.maps.event.addDomListener() is deprecated warning
 });
```

This will never work **Because there is no `google.maps.event.addEventListener`**

```
 google.maps.event.addEventListener( radioButton, 'click', function() { 
    autocomplete.setTypes( ['establishment'] ); 
   });

// lands you: Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.event.addEventListener is not a function
```

You need to rethink+rewrite as follows:

```
document.getElementById(radioButton).addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    autocomplete.setTypes( ['establishment'] ); // yellowstone PARK
    autocomplete.setTypes( ['address'] ); // some address with yellowstone st
    });
```

now this works as expected once again with no `google.maps.event.addDomListener() is deprecated` error
[image]

So in your case if you can not add `&callback=initAutocomplete` onto your URL for some reason or do not want to - then consider this:

```
// notworksolutions
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeAutocomplete);
google.maps.event.addEventListener(window, 'load', initializeAutocomplete);

// solution that work
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => { initializeAutocomplete(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

This in the Google Maps Issue Tracker marked as fixed. The fix should be a forthcoming release.