# Remove Event Listener method for a toggle

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, toggle

I have a simple click function, that when a button is clicked the user can't scroll.  This all works OK. The button works as toggle though, and on the 'else' part of the toggle, i.e. when the user clicks again, I want to remove the event listener that stop the user scrolling with the `removeEventListener();` method.  The function I am calling within this method isn't working though?

I can't seem to work out what the problem is?

codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/MrBvzP

JS

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");

// function to be called and removed when button is clicked
function noscroll() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

// TOGGLE EVENT LISTENER
var scrollToggle = false;

function toggleEventListener() {
    if (scrollToggle === false) {

        window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
        noscroll();        
        }, false);

      scrollToggle = true;

    } else {

        window.removeEventListener("scroll", function(){
        noscroll();        
        }, false);

      scrollToggle = false;

    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    toggleEventListener();
}, false)
```

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 150vh;}

#button {font-family: arial;
  margin: 10px 0 0 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">Click Me</div>
```

Comment: This can be achieved with 6 lines of code. You don't have to bind and unbind the event listeners.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe you can [remove an anonymous event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106605/removing-an-anonymous-event-listener). You need to name it so it knows which listener matches. We can reuse your `noscroll` function as our named handler.

Try running the snippet and you will see that it has your expected outcome.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");

// function to be called and removed when button is clicked
function noscroll() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

// TOGGLE EVENT LISTENER
var scrollToggle = false;

function toggleEventListener() {
    if (scrollToggle === false) {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", noscroll, false);
        scrollToggle = true;
    } else {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", noscroll, false);
        scrollToggle = false;
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    toggleEventListener();
}, false)
```

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 150vh;}

#button {font-family: arial;
  margin: 10px 0 0 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">Click Me</div>
```

We can simplify this further by moving our logic to check `scrollToggle` into the handler itself. Removing the need to add/remove the handler. (And it can stay anonymous.)

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");

// TOGGLE EVENT LISTENER
var scrollToggle = false;

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => { 
  if (scrollToggle) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0) 
  }
}, false);

function toggleEventListener() {
  scrollToggle = !scrollToggle;
}

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  toggleEventListener();
}, false)
```

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 150vh;}

#button {font-family: arial;
  margin: 10px 0 0 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">Click Me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this method?

```
window.removeEventListener("scroll", noscroll);
```