# How to solve failed to removeEventListener?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, dom-events

I want to stop the eventListener after the function is done,
here  is the illustration:

I made an icon and when clicked  it gonna show the `input form` and then when my cursor `clicked` or `mouseover` it shows the `button` search again below that input, but when I click again and over, the button search keep adding the element buttons on below,

Here is the code :

```
 let FunFun = document.querySelector( "img#pic" ).addEventListener( "click", () => {
     let newEl = document.createElement("input");
      newEl.id   = "inPut"
      newEl.type = "text";
      newEl.name = "foo";
      newEl.value = "";
      newEl.placeholder  = "type your city";
     let oldEl = document.querySelector("#pic")

     //parentEL
     let parentEl = document.querySelector( ".addCity" )
      parentEl.replaceChild( newEl, oldEl )

     let btN = document.querySelector( "#inPut" ).addEventListener( "click", () => {
       btN = document.createElement( "button" )
       btN.class = "btn0"
       btN.textContent = "search"
       let _input  = document.querySelector("#inPut")
       _input.after(btN)
// tried wrote  code removeEventListener also, but nothing error and cant make the event stop

      }) end the btN

      // console.log(btN)

   // let buttnRm = document.querySelector("#inPut").removeEventListener("click", () => {  console.log("test" )});

    }) // end  the FunFun
```

My code above was no error on the console, and I tried to put the removeEven listener below the function `btN` , it got error, like the code above,

I tried to make code like this on function above :

```
.addEventListener("click", myFunction, true) // false

.removeEventListener("click", myFunction, true) // false
```

i switch true and false above, but still nothing

some pics of the buttons showing more and more when I click the `input` form element, after my function `addeventlistener` working

[image: this is when I clicked the input form for times, it keep adding buttons, over]

[image: before click / mousenter on input form]

Comment: Please include a working example

Comment: just upload the pic, that is the pic before i click, and when i click the input form, it show one button, and when i click again, it show agai over and over

Comment: Read the documentation of [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). You have to remove the actual listener, not another listener with the same `type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Anonymous Event Listeners cannot be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106605/removing-an-anonymous-event-listener)

First you'll have to declare a function `eventHandler` to be your event listener, and then remove it later with `removeEventListener`

```
let eventHandler = () => {
   btN = document.createElement( "button" )
   btN.class = "btn0"
   btN.textContent = "search"
   let cityInput = document.querySelector( "#inPut" )
   cityInput.after(btN)

   // Remove the eventListener just after the first call
   cityInput.removeEventListener('click' , eventHandler, true)
}
```

Select the input element and store it as variable.

```
let cityInput = document.querySelector( "#inPut" ); // select the input element
cityInput.addEventListener( "click", eventHandler, true) // add a non-anonymous function as event listener
```

```js
let FunFun = document.querySelector( "img#pic" ).addEventListener( "click", () => {
 let newEl = document.createElement("input");
  newEl.id   = "inPut"
  newEl.type = "text";
  newEl.name = "foo";
  newEl.value = "";
  newEl.placeholder  = "type your city";
 let oldEl = document.querySelector("#pic")

 //parentEL
 let parentEl = document.querySelector( ".addCity" )
  parentEl.replaceChild( newEl, oldEl )

let eventHandler = () => {
   btN = document.createElement( "button" )
   btN.class = "btn0"
   btN.textContent = "search"
   cityInput.after(btN)

   cityInput.removeEventListener('click' , eventHandler, true)
}

let cityInput = document.querySelector( "#inPut" );
cityInput.addEventListener( "click", eventHandler, true) // end the btN
 
  // console.log(btN)

// let buttnRm = document.querySelector("#inPut").removeEventListener("click", () => {  console.log("test" )});

}) // end  the FunFun
```

```css
#pic {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class='addCity'>
  <img src='something.jpg' id='pic'>
</div>
```

Comment: document.querySelector( "#inPut" ).  i want to make this input when click, did u miss this on above codes, sorry

Comment: @ZrClassic when someone clicks on the image, `#input` is formed always, that is what the first few lines of function `FunFun` are doing. Can you explain me more what are you saying?

Comment: PERFECT buddy !!,  it worked like i wanted ,, thank you very much