# How to get a HTML5 page to change when fullscreen

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a simple index.html file as a landing page that displays a fullscreen gif:

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Full-screen animated gif background</title>
    <style>
        /* NOTE: The styles were added inline because Prefixfree needs access to your styles and they must be inlined if they are on local disk! */
        html { 
          background:  url(https://media.giphy.com/media/2s0ouek7HJmWQ/giphy.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
          background-size: cover;
        }
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Let's call that **A**. I have another version (**B**) that displays a fullscreen page of [particles](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js):

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Particles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="particles-js">
        <div class="btext">
            <h1>logo here</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json')
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### css/style.css

```
html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#111;
}
#particles-js{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

How can I have the page show **A** and then when the user clicks anywhere on the screen it fades to **B**?

I'm a beginner with HTML and CSS so thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you like to use JavaScript or CSS? I see you’ve put JavaScript as a tag.

Comment: @LloydNicholson TBH I'm open to either, but definitely prefer simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the opacity property in CSS.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.getElementById('gif').classList.add('fade');
 });
 document.getElementById('particles-js').addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
 console.log('boop');
 });
```

```css
html { 
        }
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }
div, img {
position:fixed;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
#gif {
  z-index:2;
    background:  url(https://media.giphy.com/media/2s0ouek7HJmWQ/giphy.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
          background-size: cover;
  opacity:1;
}

#gif.fade {
  transition: 1s;
  opacity:0;
  z-index:-1; /* ADD THIS */
}
```

```html
<div id="gif"></div>
<div id="particles-js">
        <div class="btext">
            <h1>logo here</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
    <script>

     //particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json'); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this works! One additional issue though: The second page (B) that runs particles.js used to have functionality that responds to the cursor movement and clicks, but now it doesn't. Is this functionality somehow overwritten? I've tried to remove the `EventListener` as in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3107221/3765905), but there is still no cursor response in the [particle.js](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js) page.

Comment: You just need to change the z-index of the gif when it fades. Edited my answer to reflect this change. (The CSS)

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it. To be clear, I've pasted the top code block in you poster answer into the `<script> ... </script>` block, and uncommented the `particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json');` line. This is correct, no?

Comment: No, try adding  z-index:-1; to the #gif.fade in CSS. (Where I put the "ADD THIS" comment above.)

Comment: Ah got it, the z-index addition does it, thanks! The particle.js responsiveness is laggy, but functional.