# Removing an event listener the proper way

Tags: javascript

How do I properly remove an event listener...

```
function createMaze() {
    var x;  
    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) { 
        var mazeBlock = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(mazeBlock);
        mazeBlock.setAttribute('class', 'blockStyle');
        mazeBlock.setAttribute('id', 'mazeBlock'+x);
        mazeBlock.addEventListener( 'click', function(){ eventCall(this) } );   
    }
}

function eventCall(t) {
    alert( t.id );
    t.removeEventListener(); //...know that I'm missing something here.
// Also in my code, this remove will not happen here but be initiated somewhere else in the script.

}
```

I did bunch of [digging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106605/removing-an-anonymous-event-listener) and the top answer there suggest to add the listener to an object for easier removal but... I'm not sure how to accomplish that

Answer (score 3):

While you could save a reference to the function you call `addEventListener` with so you can remove it:

```
for (let x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
  const mazeBlock = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(mazeBlock);
  mazeBlock.className = 'blockStyle';
  mazeBlock.id = 'mazeBlock' + x;
  mazeBlock.addEventListener('click', function handler() {
    mazeBlock.removeEventListener('click', handler);
    eventCall(mazeBlock);
  });
}
```

(above, `eventCall` is called with the `<div>` as the first argument)

It would be easier to make sure the function can only be called once by passing `{ once: true }` as a third argument to `addEventListener`:

```
mazeBlock.addEventListener( 'click', eventCall, { once: true });
```

(above, `eventCall` is called with the event as the first argument - to get to the `<div>`, access the `.target` of the argument)

If you need to remove listeners for *all* such elements, you might consider a different approach - rather than attaching lots of listeners and then removing them all, use event delegation instead. That way, all you have to do is remove the *single* delegated listener:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function handler(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.blockStyle')) return;
  // A block was clicked on, remove the listener:
  document.body.removeEventListener('click', handler);
  // Do stuff with the clicked element:
  eventCall(event.target);
});
```

If you're forced by weird school rules to add listeners to each element, create the listener function outside the loop, then iterate over all elements and remove the listener from each when needed:

```
const handler = (event) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.blockStyle').forEach((div) => {
    div.removeEventListener('click', handler);
  });
  // do stuff with event and event.target
};
```

Comment: Thanks. It does work when the `removeEventListener` is within the `handler()` but I need to apply this in bulk from another location in the script, finding all elements by className 'blockStyle' and removing their respective event listeners

Comment: You need to remove the listeners on *all* elements with that class name, is that it?

Comment: Yes. I'm doing `getElementsByClassName('blockStyle')` and looping through that array with `i.removeEventListener('click', handler)` but with no effect..

Comment: Each element has a different `handler`, so that method doesn't work - use event delegation instead, as shown in the answer

Comment: Thank you. Have to stick to certain procedure here (school project).

Answer (score 0):

...ended up doing this:

```
function createMaze() {
    var x;  
    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) { 
        const mazeBlock = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(mazeBlock);
        mazeBlock.className = 'blockStyle';
        mazeBlock.id = 'mazeBlock' + x;
        mazeBlock.addEventListener( 'click', eventCall );
    }
}

function eventCall() {
    alert( this.id );
}

//...this is called from another piece of the script on a separate occasion
function removeListeners() {
    var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('blockStyle');
    for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        var block = blocks[i];
        block.removeEventListener( 'click', eventCall );
    }
}
```

@CertainPerformance Thanks for all your help! :)