# How to override event prevent default in event listener?

Tags: jquery

I have a script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

window.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
},{passive:false});

});
```

So now I need to make another function when on click of a button to override the above script and to "return" the default behavior.

I tested this:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    window.off('mousewheel');
});
```

And it's not working.

EDIT 2:

Just tested this and still not working:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    window.removeEventListener('mousewheel', function(e){
        return true;
    }, true);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

Comment: @Justinas No I just tested this and does not work, the prevent default is still doing its thing.

Comment: Did you try just to remove the handler?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff Hmm, how can I achieve this

Comment: You cannot remove anonymous event listeners with `removeEventListener`. Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809957/443523

Comment: As @ClausBönnhoff said you can remove the listener this way, just by passing the addEventListener a function reference, that you will use later to remove it.

`var myEventListner = function (e) ...;`
`window.addEventListener('mousewheel', myEventListner);`

and later :

`window.removeEventListener("mousewheel", myEventListner);`

Comment: @tmb Just tested it! Works perfectly!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works Fine!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function foo(e) {
    console.log("mousewheel");
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  window.addEventListener('mousewheel', foo, true);

  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    console.log("click");
    window.removeEventListener('mousewheel', foo, true);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Button</button>
```

Comment: Yes this is just what I tested and it worked great!