# Failed to store the reference of event handler (I want to remove the event listener)

Tags: javascript

As the following code, when I click the "play round" button, it add an click event listener for each three options: `Rock`, `Paper` and `Scissors`. When they are ready, they turn to yellow.

When player pick one of them, the event listener need to be removed (prevent from miss click again).

According to this answer [Removing an anonymous event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3107221/3043719), I store the event handler reference when creating the event listener. It doesn't work. In the following code, we still can pick all three options.

```js
const playerSelection = function(selected, selections) {
    selected.id = 'selected';
    selections.forEach((selection) => {
        selection.classList.remove('listening');
        // get the anonymous event handler by cached reference
        selection.removeEventListener('click', selection.clickHandler, false);
    }); 
}

const playRound = function() {
    const selections = document.querySelectorAll(".selection");
    selections.forEach((selection) => {
        selection.id = undefined;
        selection.classList.add('listening');
        selection.addEventListener('click', function clicked() {
            // trying to store the reference of event handler
            selection.clickHandler = clicked; 
            playerSelection(selection, selections);
        }, false);
    });
};

const round = document.querySelector(".round");
round.addEventListener('click', playRound);
```

```css
.selection,
.round {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

.selection.listening {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#selected {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
    <div data-name="Rock" class="selection">Rock</div>
    <div data-name="Paper" class="selection">Paper</div>
    <div data-name="Scissors" class="selection">Scissors</div>
    <div class="round">Play a round</div>
```

The event listener was not removed. Debugging tool showed the `selection.clickHandler` property is `undefined` when `playerSelection` is called.
[image]

[image]

When I go back to `playRound` function, I'm sure that `selection.clickHandler` attribute  well setted.
[image]

[image]

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store your handler **before** adding the eventListener:

```js
const playerSelection = function(selected, selections) {
    selected.id = 'selected';
    selections.forEach((selection) => {
        selection.classList.remove('listening');
        // get the anonymous event handler by cached reference
        selection.removeEventListener('click', selection.clickHandler, false);
    }); 
}

const playRound = function() {
    const selections = document.querySelectorAll(".selection");
    selections.forEach((selection) => {
        selection.id = undefined;
        selection.classList.add('listening');
        selection.clickHandler = function() {
            playerSelection(selection, selections);
        }
        selection.addEventListener('click', selection.clickHandler, false);
    });
};

const round = document.querySelector(".round");
round.addEventListener('click', playRound);
```

```css
.selection,
.round {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

.selection.listening {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#selected {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-name="Rock" class="selection">Rock</div>
    <div data-name="Paper" class="selection">Paper</div>
    <div data-name="Scissors" class="selection">Scissors</div>
    <div class="round">Play a round</div>
```

Comment: it works. I wonder what's the difference between "store before" and "store after". Why the reference is not stored if I save it after adding the event listener.

Comment: @shen, when you're trying to store `clicked` within itself, it's not visible from within and you're getting undefined as `clicked` is not defined in the function's scope.

Comment: thx. really helpful :)