# How to remove an anonymous function from a component event in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, anonymous-function

In my component, I have:

```js
<StyledPill
    key={`styled-pill-${idx}`}
    size="small"
    label={searchType.label}
    onClick={() => handleClick(idx + 1)}
    featured={selectedSearchType === idx + 1}
/>
```

where:

```js
const handleClick = (index: number) => {
    setSelectedSearchType(index);
};
```

However, I was told that we don't want to have anonymous functions `() => handleClick(idx + 1)`. Is there some performant way to avoid it?

I can't do `onClick={handleClick}` because then I can't pass the argument.

Looking for some help - any would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing an anonymous event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106605/removing-an-anonymous-event-listener)

Comment: Where does `idx` come from?

Comment: "However, I was told" ... by whom? Why?

Comment: Is this inside an array map?

Comment: @AKX - from someone reviewing my PR. `idx` is from a `.map`

Comment: Then let the dude who's reviewing your PR come with a better solution!

Comment: Maybe you can use `.bind(this, idx + 1)`

Comment: Better dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810914/react-js-onclick-cant-pass-value-to-method

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina `.bind()` also creates new functions, no improvement there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid creating an anonymous handler for each element by making the per-item data available on the element, and reading it in the event handler.

However, this is a premature optimization that you probably don't need.

```
function Component({ searchTypes, selectedSearchType, handleClick }) {
  const handleItemClick = React.useCallback((event) => {
    const itemId = parseInt(event.target.dataset.index);
    handleClick(itemId);
  }, [handleClick]);
  return (
    <>
      {searchTypes.map((searchType, idx) => (
        <StyledPill
          key={`styled-pill-${idx}`}
          size="small"
          label={searchType.label}
          data-index={idx + 1}
          onClick={handleItemClick}
          featured={selectedSearchType === idx + 1}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, if you really would like to do it and have access to the `StyledPill` component, an option could be to accept `onClick` and `index` as props, then write a wrapper function to call the `onClick` with the `index`.

```js
<StyledPill
    key={`styled-pill-${idx}`}
    size="small"
    label={searchType.label}
    onClick={handleClick}
    index={idx + 1}
    featured={selectedSearchType === idx + 1}
/>
```

```
// StyledPill.jsx

function StyledPill({onClick, index}) {
    function handleOnClick() {
        onClick(index);
    }
    
    return (
        <button onClick={handleOnClick} .../>
    )
}
```

Comment: And if you don't have access to the `StyledPill` component (for instance it is created with `styled-components`), you'd have to create a wrapper component.

Comment: This will still create a `handleOnClick` per `StyledPill`. No improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that like this, which is also called point-free style

```
const handleClick = (index: number) => () => {
    setSelectedSearchType(index);
};

// ...

<StyledPill
    key={`styled-pill-${idx}`}
    size="small"
    label={searchType.label}
    onClick={handleClick(idx + 1)}
    featured={selectedSearchType === idx + 1}
/>
```

Codesandbox Demo

[image: Edit hopeful-northcutt-2ucy4q]

Comment: This won't work, since you're now calling `handleClick` immediately.

Comment: In `Vue` this would be possible, but not `React`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699573/correct-use-of-arrow-functions-in-react

Comment: @AKX Since you said that it would not work, I have made an example, please find it here https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-northcutt-2ucy4q?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @Konstantin please check the example https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-northcutt-2ucy4q?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Well, for one, you edited the code since my comment, so okay, it does work. Secondly, this still creates new functions, so it's the same thing as the original, but with one named function more.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to pass a named function to the `onClick` handler you could define the function inside your `map()` callback:

```
function Component({ searchTypes, selectedSearchType, handleClick }) {
  const handleClick = (index: number) => {
    setSelectedSearchType(index);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {searchTypes.map((searchType, idx) => {
        const handlePillClick = () => handleClick(idx + 1);

        return (
          <StyledPill
            key={`styled-pill-${idx}`}
            size="small"
            label={searchType.label}
            data-index={idx + 1}
            onClick={handlePillClick}
            featured={selectedSearchType === idx + 1}
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This also creates an extra function per pill. No improvement.

Comment: @AKX but it's named instead of anonymous.

Comment: You could just as well do `onClick={function handlePillClick() { handleClick(idx + 1); }}` but that's likely not the point.