# How to refer to the first object called?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code:

```
var Person = {
 "name": "",
 "changes": {
  "name to": function(value) {
   this["name"] = value;
  }
 }
}

var Josh = Object.create(Person);
Josh["changes"]["name to"]("John");

console.log(Josh.name); // nothing
console.log(Josh.changes.name); // "John"
```

The problem is that this above refers to Object "changes" and not object instance "Josh".

I can't replace this with Person because then it's referring to the object "Person" and not to the object instance "Josh".

Is it possible to refer to Josh's name?

Comment: What is the "changes" object for? It doesn't appear to serve any purpose. It'd be more natural to have a `Person.changeName()` function.

Comment: This was just a simplification of the actual implementation. The principle is the same though.

Comment: From an OO pov, it seems a bit strange. An object is supposed to encapsulate data and methods to operate on that data. You're isolating your methods to another object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the more common form of Javascript OOP?

```
function Person() {
    this.name = "";
    this.changes = {};
    var _this = this;
    this.changes.nameTo = function(name) {
        _this.name = name;
    }
}

var Josh = new Person();
Josh.changes.nameTo("John");

console.log(Josh.name); // "John"
console.log(Josh.changes.name); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not. You don't have any reference to an enclosing instance of the object you're in currently. You need to move the method to the outer `Person` object.

```
var Person = {
 "name": "",
 "changeNameTo": function(value) {
   this["name"] = value;
 }
}
```

*Edit:* If you absolutely want the original structure, albeit strange from an OO perspective. You need to give the inner object a reference to the outer. Programatically you can do it as below - or perhaps do it in a constructor, depending on your framework providing the `Object.create()` method.

```
var Person = {
 "name": "",
 "changes": {
  "name to": function(value) {
   this.data["name"] = value;
  }
 }
}

var Josh = Object.create(Person);
Josh.changes.data = Josh;

Josh["changes"]["name to"]("John");
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to use caller/callee to get the first object called: Josh["changes"]["name to"]("John") which in this case is Josh?

Comment: Ha! Yeah, I suppose - but that's so obscure, I'd completely forgotten about it. Seems it's deprecated even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript

Comment: Do you know how I could use caller/callee in my case to get Object Josh?

Comment: Hm.. on second thoughts, I was confused. `Josh["changes"]["name to"]("John");` The `arguments.callee` is the inner function, but `arguments.callee.caller` is (of course) not the outer.