# Underscore.js : findWhere with nested property value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How do I go about the filtering below:

```
[{
    "id": 100,
    "title": "Tlt1",
    "tax": [{
        "name": "Tax1",
        "id": 15
    }, {
        "name": "Tax1",
        "id": 17
    }]
}, {
    "id": 101,
    "title": "Tlt2",
    "tax": [{
        "name": "Tax2",
        "id": 16
    }]
}, {
    "id": 102,
    "title": "Tlt3",
    "tax": [{
        "name": "Tax3",
        "id": 17
    }, {
        "name": "Tax3",
        "id": 18
    }]
}]
```

to get only those where `tax.id` is `17`, as per below:

```
[
    {
        "id": 100,
        "title": "Tlt1",
        "tax": [
            {
                "name": "Tax1",
                "id": 15
            },
            {
                "name": "Tax1",
                "id": 17
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 102,
        "title": "Tlt3",
        "tax": [
            {
                "name": "Tax3",
                "id": 17
            },
            {
                "name": "Tax3",
                "id": 18
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Currently I use the method below, but maybe there is more clean way of going about this?

```
var arr = [];
_(data).each(function (v1, k1) {
    _(v1.tax).each(function (v2, k2) {
        if (v2.id == id) {
            arr.push(v1);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/7gcCz/2/

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: This could be a candidate for CR ...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You may use the combination of `_.filter` and `_.where`

```
_.filter(data, function(obj) {
    return _.where(obj.tax, {id: ID_TO_FIND}).length > 0;
})
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hCVxp/

## Update

---

Thanks to @GruffBunny. A more efficient way is to use `_.some` to avoid looping through all `tax` items:

```
var arr = _.filter(data, function(obj) {
    return _.some(obj.tax, {id: ID_TO_FIND});
});
```

See demo: http://jsbin.com/putefarade/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Fist time using `underscore`, First Roadbump, First Link on Google, FTW!

Comment: Also if tax is just an object, you must put it on an array to this thing work. Something like this _.some([obj.tax], {id: ID_TO_FIND});

Answer (score 20):

Use _.filter to find candidate items and _.some to check for the existence of an item in a collection:

```
var filteredList = _.filter(list, function(item){
    return _.some(item.tax, { id: 17 });
});
```

Comment: I think that this answer is more performant than the accepted answer above.

Comment: can i use _.findWhere inside filter?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with _.where alone.

```
var filteredList  = _.where(list, { tax:[{id:17}] });
```

Edit: This method works in older version of lodash, but wont work in current underscore or lodash. 
Working example anyway:
https://jsfiddle.net/rhp4crma/

Comment: Can someone tell me why this is being downvoted? I tested it and it returns the exact result OP asked for with only 1 command.

Comment: I tried this and it does not work. Mine returns undefined although the item is present

Comment: correct syntax is :  var filteredList  = _.where(list, { tax:{id:17} });

Comment: I have up-voted your answer to encourage you to participate in SO, please update your answer with a link to jsfiddle example for this specified case and update your answer corrector as @Sam suggested.