# underscore not filtering correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I'm trying to filter my dynamoddb results with underscore.But the filter not working.What is the problem with this.

```
var results = [{email: { S: 'mycosmedical2017@gmail.com' }];
var Users = _.where(result, { email: { S: 'mycosmedical2017@gmail.com' 
}})
console.log(Users)
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6prt6x5/1/)

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? I mean what's the result you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess its due to multilevel object, here is one way of achieving the result.

Source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600530/underscore-js-findwhere-with-nested-property-value)

```js
var result = [{
    user_info: {
        S: '{"fname":"Sanumi","lname":"Niromi"}'
    }, 
    email: { S: 'vindyavishwani@yahoo.com' },
    mobileNo: { S: '1234567890' }
},
{
    user_info: { S: '{"fname":"Arya","lname":"Stark","prefname":"Vindi"}' },
    email: { S: 'mycosmedical2017@gmail.com' },
    mobileNo: { S: '0777773425' }
},
{
    user_info: { S: '{"fname":"Mohamed","lname":"Nizar"}' },
    email: { S: 'nizarucsc@gmail.com' }
},
{
    user_info: { S: '{"fname":"Sansa","lname":"Stark"}' },
    email: { S: 'vindya@proitzen.com' }
}];

var Users = _.filter(result, function(item){
    return _.some(item, { S: 'vindyavishwani@yahoo.com' });
});

console.log(Users)


/** expected
[ { user_info: { S: '{"fname":"Arya","lname":"Stark","prefname":"Vindi"}' },
email: { S: 'mycosmedical2017@gmail.com' },
mobileNo: { S: '0777773425' } },]
**/
```

```css
.as-console {
    height: 100%;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```