# Using findWhere with nested objects in an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a data structure that looks like this

```
var foo = [
    {
        bar: {
            something: 123
        },
        baz: {
            somethingElse: 321
        }
    },
    {
        bar: {
            something: 444
        },
        baz: {
            somethingElse: 555
        }
    }
];
```

I then have a variable:

```
var findMe = 444;
```

I'd like to search through my `foo` data structure (an array of objects) to see if `findMe` matches the `bar.something` property of any of the objects inside the `foo` array.

Using underscore.js, I would have thought the following code snippet would do the trick:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var thingImLookingFor = _.findWhere(foo, {bar.something: findMe});
```

However that produces a syntax error in my application:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Is anyone able to shed some light on how I can achieve the search I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: you'll need to perform a deep find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578725/underscore-js-findwhere-nested-objects

Comment: or you can try something with JSONPath http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Comment: @YarGnawh thanks for the responses :) Fortunately because it is certain exactly how deep the search is and exactly what keys need to be searched I can use find(). I'm not sure of the performance implications the approach has but from my benchmarks it looks fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the solution to my question.

_.find() does what I want quite nicely.

```
_.find(foo, function(obj) {
    return obj.bar.something == findMe;
});
```